# How can I customise the worldpay help pages?

Tags: customization, worldpay

The world pay advanced customisation documentation ([here](http://www.worldpay.com/support/kb/bg/pdf/custa.pdf)) explains how to customise most of the world pay pages. I have managed to customise the payment pages, cancelation page and payment failure page so far by creating and uploading custom header.html, footer.html and stylesheet.css files. I've also had to customise resultC.html and resultR.html so they include the stylesheet and headers and footers of the other files. This has all been fairly simple so far; all the files have specified download locations and all just get uploaded to the same place.

Now, on page 78 of the documentation I've linked to at the top, it shows how the links to the help pages are defined for the links in header.html. For example, the security link is defined with these properties:

```
header.tabthree=Security
header.tabthreelinkaddress=/global3/brands/worldpay/payment/default/help_security_en.html
```

The address linked to there is the same address as is given in the documentation as the location of the default help page for security, so obviously this isn't going to link to a customised version no matter how many files I upload.

I've tried uploading a custom security page (a link to the default is provided in the documentation) and navigating to that just through changing my browser address to try and find it - this hasn't worked.

I've tried linking to 'help_security_en.html' rather than '/global3/brands/worldpay/payment/default/help_security_en.html' and a few other variations. None of these have worked either.

- Is it possible to customise these pages?
- Where do I upload the customised page to?
- How do I link to the customised page?

I suppose I could just create the help pages on the original website and link to them from the world pay sections, but I'd rather stick to having all the world pay stuff in one place if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

Download the help files here:

https://secure.worldpay.com/global3/brands/worldpay/payment/default/help_en.html
https://secure.worldpay.com/global3/brands/worldpay/payment/default/help_faqs_en.html
https://secure.worldpay.com/global3/brands/worldpay/payment/default/help_security_en.html

Then create a properties file called messages_en.properties and include this:

```
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Default Header
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
header.tabone=Help
header.tabonelinkaddress=/i/<your_id>/help_en.html
header.tabtwo=FAQs
header.tabtwolinkaddress=/i/<your_id>/help_faqs_en.html
header.tabthree=Security
header.tabthreelinkaddress=/i/<your_id>/help_security_en.html
```

Then you can customise the files and upload them through the File Manager.

Hope that helps.